# SmtpClient error when recipient list is 101 email address

Tags: c#, email

Is there any limitation on the size of the recipient list? I have a simple program that read the email address from the database and sends out an email with an attachment.
It works FINE when I test it with just 3 email address but I get the below error when I use the complete recipient list of 101.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no limit of the number of to addresses on a `MailMessage`. This is probably a limit of your smtp server.

Comment: Why not use a distribution list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell by just what you provided but you should be aware that when you're sending an email to an SMTP server, it looks at the recipients before accepting all of your data and it does a lookup for each email address before it continues. Sometimes, SMTP servers are a bit slow with the lookup and tend to time out. That could be your issue and if it is, it's pretty much out of your control unless you own the mail server and you can tweak it in some way.

Comment: Thank you for response.. but in Powershell I do the exact same thing pull email list from db and send out email and works fine with 101 email address. So not sure why in c# I get that error message. I will do some more research.

Comment: Just an update.. I retest using 50 email address then 75, then 95, then 100 all worked fine as soon as I hit 101 email address is when it erros out. I can't believe it :( It has to be a limitation but I couldn't find any documentation on this limintation... I am using .net 3.5 .

Comment: One last update... In powershell I was using 100 email addresses cause I was BCCing myself.. so must be a limitation on my company's  smpt server.. SO I guess I will put a 100 in the TO and anohter 100 in the CC.